# Drag and Drop into a Scheduler Timeline from a Third Party Component

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dhtmlx

Having read 
[this page on external drag and drop](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/dhtmlx_components_integration.html) at DHTMLX’s site, I am concluding that I can drag and drop from an external DHTMLX component but not from a third party or self-written component.

I have included the drag and drop javascript module:

```
ext/dhtmlxscheduler_outerdrag.js
```

I have created a dummy event handler:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onExternalDragIn", function (id, source, event) {
    return true;
});
```

I have written a drag event that’s attached to my component:

**html**:

```
<div draggable="{{item.draggable}}" data-itemid="{{item.id}}"
    ondragstart="drag(event, this.getAttribute('data-itemid'))">
```

**js**:

```
function drag(ev, itemId) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", itemId);
}
```

But... I don’t know how to implement `drop` with the scheduler timeline component.

I have tried this:

**html**:

```
<div id="scheduler1" class="dhx_cal_container" ondrop="drop(event)" 
    ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

**js**:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
}
```

... but all that does is fire a generic event when I drop something onto the grid. I (obviously) get no information as to which grid cell I’ve dropped onto. How would I go about coding this to know which row/column I’ve landed on?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [this related question](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=37916) at DHTMLX’s site.

Turns out that all I was missing was a call to `getActionData()` in my `drop` method:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var sourceData = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");   // what we dragged (the tree node in this case)
    var targetData = scheduler.getActionData(ev);       // what we dropped (.date = datetime, .section = id of section)
}
```

Also, I needed to put back the reference to `drop(event)` in the `div` that the scheduler is declared in:

```
<div id="scheduler1" class="dhx_cal_container" style="width:100%; height:620px;" 
    ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

And this `attachEvent` is extraneous:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onExternalDragIn", function (id, source, event) {
    return true;
});
```